# How to send a mail of my WebDriver Script Results?

Tags: selenium, webdriver, testng

I wrote the Script in WebDriver, its work fine and give some results in console..
 Now I want to email these scripts to my Mail. I Don't want the status, I want whole results displayed in the console. Can any body tell me the process, how to do this..    I am using Selenium WebDriver, TestNG..

Comment: You want the TestNG results on your email? Have you considered using CI?

Comment: In my script i used System.out.println(); this statement will print the output in console. Now i want to mail the out put what ever displayed in the console.

Comment: May i know what is CI? why we need it? I don't know about CI, can you explain it for me?